# isChecked is not working on checkbox Programmatically on Kotlin

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to fill a checkbox using the function ischeked but Looks like it is not working no matter what I did, I have tried with .clearFocus(), toggle(), jumpDrawablesToCurrentState() but any of that methods works, I have tried to fill it after I create my checkbox and later when I compare
the result from firebase but it is not working in any case, here is my complete code hope you can help me.

```
    private var mNameField: EditText? = null
    private var mPhoneField: EditText? = null
    private var mBack: Button? = null
    private var mConfirm: Button? = null
    private var mProfileImage: ImageView? = null
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private var mUserDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var userId: String? = null
    private var name: String? = null
    private var biografia: String? = null
    private var profileImageUrl: String? = null
    private var userSex: String? = null
    private var resultUri: Uri? = null
    private var mRadioGroupBuscar: RadioGroup? = null
    private var valormRadioGroupBuscar: RadioGroup? = null
    private lateinit var radioButtonBuscaSexo: RadioButton
    private var PC: CheckBox?=null
    private var Playstation: CheckBox?=null
    private var Xbox : CheckBox?=null
    private var Nintendo : CheckBox?=null
    private var Movil: CheckBox?=null
    private  var aString: String?=null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
        mNameField = findViewById<View>(R.id.name) as EditText
        mPhoneField = findViewById<View>(R.id.phone) as EditText
        mProfileImage = findViewById<View>(R.id.profileImage) as ImageView
        mBack = findViewById<View>(R.id.back) as Button
        mConfirm = findViewById<View>(R.id.confirm) as Button
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        userId = mAuth?.currentUser!!.uid
        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(userId!!)
        mRadioGroupBuscar = findViewById<View>(R.id.radioGroupBusca) as RadioGroup

        val selectIdBuscaSexo = mRadioGroupBuscar!!.checkedRadioButtonId
        //val radioButtonBuscaSexo = findViewById<View>(selectIdBuscaSexo) as RadioButton
        PC = findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBoxPc) as  CheckBox?

        Xbox = findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBoxXbox) as  CheckBox?
        Nintendo = findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBoxNintendo) as  CheckBox?
        Movil = findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBoxMovil) as  CheckBox?

        Playstation = findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBoxPlaytation) as CheckBox?

        //I HAVE TRIED TO CHECK MY CHECKBOX HERE
       // Playstation?.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()
      //  Playstation?.isChecked = true
        Playstation!!.clearFocus()
        Playstation!!.isChecked= true;
        
        userInfo
        mProfileImage!!.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        }
        mConfirm!!.setOnClickListener { saveUserInformation() }
        mBack!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            finish()
            return@OnClickListener
        })
    }

    private val userInfo: Unit
        private get() {
            mUserDatabase!!.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.childrenCount > 0) {
                        val map = dataSnapshot.value as Map<String, Any?>?
                        if (map!!["Name"] != null) {
                            name = map["Name"].toString()
                            mNameField!!.setText(name)
                        }
                        if (map["biografia"] != null) {
                            biografia = map["biografia"].toString()
                            mPhoneField!!.setText(biografia)
                        }
                        if (map["sexo"] != null) {
                            userSex = map["sexo"].toString()
                        }
                        if (map["Playstation"].toString() != "false") {
                            var aString = map["Playstation"].toString()
                            //HERE I tried to Cheked
                            Playstation?.isChecked
                            Playstation?.isChecked = true
                            Playstation?.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()
                        }
                        Glide.with(mProfileImage!!.context).clear(mProfileImage!!)
                        if (map["profileImageUrl"] != null) {
                            profileImageUrl = map["profileImageUrl"].toString()
                            when (profileImageUrl) {
                                "default" -> Glide.with(application).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mProfileImage!!)
                                else -> Glide.with(application).load(profileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage!!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
            })
        }

    private fun saveUserInformation() {
        name = mNameField!!.text.toString()
        biografia = mPhoneField!!.text.toString()
       var buscasex = radioButtonBuscaSexo.text.toString()
        val userInfo: java.util.HashMap<Any?, Any?> = java.util.HashMap<Any?, Any?>()
        userInfo["Name"] = name
        userInfo["biografia"] = biografia
       // userInfo["buscarSexo"] = buscasex
      //  userInfo["PC"] = checkIfItsChecked(PC!!)
        userInfo["Playstation"] = checkIfItsCheckedString(aString!!)
       // userInfo["Xbox"] = checkIfItsChecked(Xbox!!)
      //  userInfo["Nintendo"] = checkIfItsChecked(Nintendo!!)
     //   userInfo["Movile"] = checkIfItsChecked(Movil!!)
        mUserDatabase?.updateChildren(userInfo as Map<String, Any>)
        val a = 1
        if (resultUri != null) {
            val filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("profileImages").child(userId!!)
            var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(application.contentResolver, resultUri)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos)
            val data = baos.toByteArray()
            val uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data)
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener { finish() }
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                val downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl
                while (!downloadUrl.isSuccessful);
                val resultdowloadUrl: Uri? = downloadUrl.getResult()
                val userInfo: MutableMap<String, Any?> = HashMap<String, Any?>()
                Log.e("uri12",resultdowloadUrl.toString()+"This is uri of image download");
                Toast.makeText(this, resultdowloadUrl.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                userInfo.set("profileImageUrl", resultdowloadUrl.toString())
                mUserDatabase!!.updateChildren(userInfo as Map<String, Any>)
                finish()
                return@OnSuccessListener
            })
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val imageUri = data?.data
            resultUri = imageUri
            mProfileImage!!.setImageURI(resultUri)
        }
    }
    private fun checkIfItsChecked(checkBox: CheckBox): Boolean{
        return checkBox.isChecked
    }
    private fun checkIfItsCheckedString(string: String): Boolean{
        return string == "true"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setCheck()`?

Comment: `findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBoxPlaytation)` - is that typo in your layout file as well?

Comment: I have tried with setCheck() and is not working, and kotlin always recomment use only ischeck

Comment: Joozd yes its the same name I have in my layout

Comment: Can you try to comment others just let these codes only? 
`Playstation = findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBoxPlaytation) as CheckBox?
Playstation!!.isChecked= true;`

Comment: Have you tried Ticherhaz FreePalestine's suggestion?

Comment: Please make a *minimum* example that replicates the problem you are seeing (e.g. a new activity with just one CheckBox). I am not able to replicate what you reported - using `myCheckBox.isChecked = true` works as expected when I try it.

Comment: Have you tried isSelected ?